# what is the use of "-" while printing hex using printf

Tags: c, printf, esp-idf

I was going through one of the example codes of esp-idf and I found out that they were using the following syntax to print hex number.

`ESP_LOGE(TAG, "mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x%x", -ret);`

The `ESP_LOGE()` syntax just prints the output to the console through UART. I am not understanding what is the use of "-" in it. Can anyone help me why they have used "-" in it? The code which I was referring to is [here.](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/protocols/smtp_client/main/smtp_client_example_main.c) When I tried a simple example to print the same hex using C I was getting different output when I used `-ret` and when I replaced it with `ret`.

Comment: Evidently, `ret` is a negative number, so they pass `-ret` to the function, and then put a negative sign in the format string.

Comment: Yes, I realized just now. Thanks a lot, @user3386109. You can post the same answer I will accept it.

Comment: The error codes of Mbed-TLS are negative hexadecimal numbers. See the `ssl.h` header file.

Answer (score 0):

`%x` will print hex representation of the **unsigned** number.

example:

```
int x = -0x45;
printf("%x\n", x);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/j3r3nv1s1

It will print (assuming two's complement 32 bits integers) `ffffffbb` which is not you want to see if you intended to print a negative hex number. You need to convert it to a positive number and simply add `-` to the format string.  **REMEMBER** in two complement's system it will not work for INT_MIN number and it will invoke an Undefined Behaviour.

```
int x = -0x45;
printf("-%x\n", -x);  //you can also use abs(x)
```

It will output -45. https://godbolt.org/z/ePbdrcqb5

You may add `0x` as well to show that number is in hex format.

```
printf("-0x%x\n", -x);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/saqf8c9dY

Comment: With a negative `int`, `int x = -0x45; printf("%x\n", x);` is UB, not "hex representation of the unsigned number"